# Swift cache tableview json data

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I wonder if its possible to cache tableView JSON data?

In my VC I have this variable:

```
//Categories json data
var categories: JSON! = []
```

Then later inside a alamofire api call I get the json data and assign it like:

```
self.categories = JSON["catData"]
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

But is there any way to cache this data so I dont have to make a API call everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a singleton DataCache class where you can store all the data you want to cache. Prefer to store data inside a dictionary for specific key

```
class DataCache: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = DataCache()
    var cache = [String, AnyObject]()
}
```

Now in your api call, call this method

```
DataCache.sharedInstance.cache["TableViewNameKey"] = JSON["catData"]
self.categories = JSON["catData"] // Set this property for first time when you hit API
```

and in `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)` method

```
if let lCategories = DataCache.sharedInstance.cache["TableViewNameKey"] {
    self.categories = lCategories
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can sync my cache to the server? Eg if my cached data is missing a new value that the server added

Comment: For that you need to integrate some special services like realtime database service. You can try google firebase for iOS

Comment: @user2636197 For saving data, if you just need in app instance, use singleton as <iProgrammer> given above. Suppose you need to retain it, can save it as files in document directory. For syncing, the server needs support mechanism and as per server logic you have to update local stored files

Comment: @iProgrammer I had a look at it but I only need to cache some categories which are almost static data since I will update them once a year at most. But I have accepted your answer, could you please provide a more full example of your code above? Eg how do I know if I have the data cached

Answer (score 0):

Swiftlycache can be used for data caching. You can directly cache the data that complies with the codable protocol. It's very convenient. If you need it, you can try it
https://github.com/hlc0000/SwiftlyCache